# How does MySql "FROM" clause work with multiple table names?

Tags: mysql, lamp

What is a difference between following two queries:-

1. **Query 1:** SELECT ord.* FROM orders ord, order_hotels oh (return empty)
2. **Query 2:** SELECT ord.* FROM orders ord (return all records)

So, by specifying multiple table names in "FROM" clause (Query 1) even, I am not using other table will affect query result? and how?

Thanks

Comment: Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join`s.

Comment: Need some help to understand above two queries.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ to help explain table joins.  If 2 returns records, 1 will return lots more.  # of records in orders(e.g.1000) * number of records in order_Hotels(e.g.10000) (e.g. 10 million) in my example.  Perhaps it just takes too long to run.  When using two tables, you need to tell the database HOW the tables relate, what to JOIN them on; something like ORDERS.ID and order_Hotels.Order_ID assuming a primary key foreign key relationship, otherwise you get a Cartesian product (A*B) instead of A intersect B.

Comment: If `order_hotels` contains more than ` row you should get duplicate `ord` entries. Is this the exact query or did you omit some parts?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, In "orders" table, I have "34992" records and my order_hotels table is empty. In "Query 1", I just used "order_hotels" but didn't explicitly specify any relationship between "orders" and "order_hotels" tables.

Comment: well then if there's no records 34992*0 is what?  0  That's why you're not getting any records.  If you had set it up as a LEFT join, you'd get all orders and only those records matching in order_Hotels.  by nature of the query written, you're doing a CROSS JOIN.  All records relate to all records. since all records relating to 0 records is 0 records, you get no data.  Add 1 entry to order_hotels, now you get all the data from orders.. now add a second entry, you now have twice as many records right?  That's again a cross join attribute which is what you're doing in the 1st query.

Answer (score 6):

Your query with the empty result set is this, elaborated for readability

```
SELECT ord.* 
  FROM orders AS ord, order_hotels  AS oh
```

It is the old-timey comma-separated list of tables, syntax for this query

```
     SELECT ord.* 
       FROM orders AS ord
 INNER JOIN order_hotels  AS oh
```

This query, an `INNER JOIN` without any `ON` clause, returns one row for each possible pairing of rows in `orders` and `order_hotels`.  You have stated that `order_hotels` contains no rows. So, this query is dutifully returning every possible pairing, which is no rows.

If you're trying to do something interesting with these two tables even before you populate the `order_hotels` table, you might try something like this:

```
     SELECT ord.*, oh.hotel_name
       FROM orders AS ord
  LEFT JOIN order_hotels  AS oh  ON ord.hotel_id = oh.hotel_id
```

(I am guessing column names, and I may have guessed wrong.)  This `LEFT JOIN` returns a resultset that shows all the rows in `orders` with the matching rows in `order_hotels`. The `ON` clause specifies what it means for a row to match.